# Finding a Maclaurin Series solution to a 2. order linear differential equation using sigma notation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

I am stuck at the following question:

Find in the form of sigma noation, the Maclaurin series solution to:

$$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}-x \frac {dy}{dx}-y=0$$

given that $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$.

---

What I have tried:

We may assume that the equation can be written as:
$$\sum_{k=0}(k+1)(k+2) a_{k+2}x^k-x\sum_{k=0}(k+1) a_{k+1}x^k-\sum_{k=0}a_{k}x^k=0$$

This is how my textbook solved a similar example and it is the method my book expects me to use.
I then tried to find a recurrence relation (this is also the way my textbook solved a similar example):

*:

$$(k+1)(k+2) a_{k+2}-(k+1) a_{k+1}-a_{k}=0$$

Since $y(0)=1$ and $\frac y'(0)=0$ and since a maclaurin series as the form $y(0)+xy'(x)+\frac {x^2}{2!}y''(0)+...$ we can say that $a_0$=$y(0)$=$1$ and $a_1$=$\frac{y'(0)}{2!}$=$0$.

from *:
$$(0+1)(0+2) a_{0+2}-(0+1) a_{0+1}-a_{0}=0$$
$$2a_{2}-a_{1}-a_{0}=0$$
$$2a_{2}-a_{0}=0$$
$$a_{2}=\frac {a_{0}}2$$

using * repeatetly:

$$(1+1)(1+2) a_{1+2}-(1+1) a_{1+1}-a_{1}=0$$
$$6a_{3}-2a_{2}-a_{1}=0$$
$$6a_{3}-2a_{2}=0$$
$$6a_{3}=2a_{2}$$
$$6a_{3}=a_{0}$$
$$a_{3}=\frac{a_{0}}6$$

and $a_4=\frac {a_0}{12}$, $a_5=\frac {a_0}{40}$...

Since $a_n$ is the factor of every $n$th term of the maclaurin series:
$$y=a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4x^4+a_5x^5...$$
$$y=a_0 + \frac {a_{0}}2 x^2 + \frac{a_{0}}6 x^3 + \frac {a_0}{12} x^4+ \frac {a_0}{40} x^5...$$

But I do not see a pattern to write it using sigma notation. In fact, I know that it is wrong since my textbook says that the solution is:

$$y = \sum_{n=0}\frac {x^{2n}}{2^nn!}$$

which is something different.

Could anybody explain how to arrive at the correct answer and tell me what I did wrong? I would be really nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the leading $x$ in the series for the first derivative:

$$\begin{align}
0&=\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1)(k+2) a_{k+2}x^k-x\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1) a_{k+1}x^k-\sum_{k\ge0}a_{k}x^k\\[1ex]
&=\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}x^k-\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k+1}-\sum_{k\ge0}a_kx^k\\[1ex]
&=\color{red}{\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}x^k}-\sum_{k\ge1}ka_kx^k-\color{blue}{\sum_{k\ge0}a_kx^k}\\[1ex]
&=\color{red}{2a_2}-\color{blue}{a_0}+\sum_{k\ge1}\bigg((k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}-(k+1)a_k\bigg)x^k\\[1ex]
&=\sum_{k\ge0}\bigg((k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}-(k+1)a_k\bigg)x^k
\end{align}$$

From here, you have the recurrence

$$\begin{cases}a_0=1\\a_1=0\\a_{k+2}=\frac1{k+2}a_k&\text{for }k>1\end{cases}$$

so that

$$\{a_k\}_{k\ge0}=\left\{1,0,\frac12,0,\frac18,0,\frac1{48},0,\frac1{384},\ldots\right\}$$

The odd-indexed terms vanish, and for the even-indexed ones ($k=2n$) you have

$$a_{2n}=\frac{a_{2(n-1)}}{2n}=\frac{a_{2(n-2)}}{2^2n(n-1)}=\cdots=\frac{a_0}{2^nn!}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot that you worked through the question, I got the series after you told me where my mistake was, but not in a generalized form. However, I do not fully understand how you got the middle sum in line 3 ($\sum_{k≥1} ka_k x^k$). Could you try to explain how you got to the term?

Comment: That's a simple index shift: replace $k+1$ with $k$ (or alternatively, replace $k$ with $k-1$), so that$$\sum_{k\ge0}(k+1)a_{k+1}x^{k+1}=\sum_{k-1\ge0}((k-1)+1)a_{(k-1)+1}x^{(k-1)+1}=\sum_{k\ge1}ka_kx^k$$

Comment: I somehow did not see how it worked but it now makes sense.Thanks for elaborating it cleared up my confusion!